# How to get class name of current node with xpath?

Tags: python, xpath

How can one identify if the current node contains a particular class name with xpath?

Case: I iterate through a list where one element is special that needs to be identified.

e.g. the list with two class names:

```
<div class="box special">
```

Cycle through all list elements:

```
for selector in response.xpath(
                    "//div[contains(@class, 'List')]/div[contains(@class, 'box')]"):
    # in case this list element is special remember it as "found"
    if selector.xpath('[contains(@class, 'special')]').extract_first() = 'special':
         found = 1
    else:
         found = 0
    ...
```

The current selector for `'special'` does not work. How could I identify the current class name?

Comment: That `.xpath` is not from core python, so you should really state what library you are using for that, and also add the appropriate tag. I'm gonna guess it's Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the second XPath query, just inspect the selector's `class` attribute to see if it is special:

```
if "special" in selector.attrib.get("class", ""):
    ...
```

There's an example in Scrapy's docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#selecting-element-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
for selector in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'List')]/div[contains(@class, 'box')]"):
      if selector.xpath("contains(@class,'special')"):
         [do something]
```